# Reason that BluetoothLEDevice FromIdAsync returns a disconnected device?

Tags: windows, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm running a UWP/C# app in Windows 10 and attempting to connect to a Bluetooth LE device (that was successfully paired) using BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync().  It returns a device object, but it's always in a disconnected state.  I've tried re-pairing the device multiple times, but it doesn't help.  This device successfully connects in other environments - it's just Windows/UWP where I'm having trouble.  Thoughts?  After pairing, should a consent dialog automatically appear when attempting to connect?

Comment: Have you tried to subscribe to BluetoothLeDevice.ConnectionStatusChanged ? What kind of pairing do you use and what is the result ? There is no consent dialog for connection AFAIK, for pairing maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You must interact with it in order to connect to it, for example read/write some GATT value. You can also enable notifications for some characteristic which then will make the Bluetooth stack have a connection open to the device.

Comment: I considered that too, but attempting to read/write a value threw an exception.  I actually think it might be a timing issue.  If I attempt to connect after the first Added event raised from a DeviceWatcher, I get a BluetoothLEDevice in a disconnected state.  But connecting upon subsequent Added/Updated events yields a device in a connected state.  Perhaps the device was simply not ready.